# How to delete selected text in nano editor?

Tags: text-editor, nano

How do I delete selected text in the nano editor?

I came across this issue while needing to delete the virtual host file and replace its content completely by other content. But the problem is that I can't select and delete the entire text at once. And if I delete it character by character, it won't be a computer thing.

Comment: No, It's not duplicate. I am particularly asking for deleting the selected content that is not available on link you are saying to be duplicate of.

Comment: your question seems to me like problem in editing a text, now I can understand that you are asking about selecting text using mouse and delete... see my answer...

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can't select with mouse and delete text using `nano editor`. For faster delete you can use `Ctrl + K` to delete(cut) the present line of text.

Note : `Ctrl + K` will cut the line of text. Using `Ctrl + U` you can paste it.

**EDIT: Additional Info from [steeldriver](https://askubuntu.com/users/178692/steeldriver)**

You can select and cut something other than the current line using `Ctrl-^` to mark the start of the text, then advancing the cursor e.g. using `Ctrl-F` (forward one character) and/or `Ctrl-Space` (forward one word) and/or arrow keys, and then pressing `Ctrl-K`

Comment: You can select and cut something other than the current line using `Ctrl-^` to mark the start of the text, then advancing the cursor e.g. using `Ctrl-F` (forward one character) and/or `Ctrl-Space` (forward one word) and/or arrow keys, and __then__ pressing `Ctrl-K`

Comment: like @steeldriver said.. that's how you delete in nano! First set the mark with `Ctrl + ^`, then select with arrow keys, use the cut `Ctrl + K` and  to delete, don't follow that by a paste `Ctrl + U`;) To copy the key combo is `Alt + ^`

Comment: So is the simple answer 'hold down the Backspace/Delete key?' :) +1 Very useful

Comment: like @steeldriver said.. for selection you can use `SHIFT+ARROW` to move any direction. And for Mac or if  `Ctrl-^ ` not work then `CTRL+SHIFT+^` should work.

Comment: Also, you can enable the mouse in Nano if invoked with -m option or `set mouse` in ~/.nanorc You can set the mark with the mouse with a double-click.